# why do we need to add properties for public fields?

Tags: java, encapsulation

I interested in encapsulation todays and I have a basic question for that. I understand why I need to add setter and getter methods for private fields. but I see that write for public int , String something else setter and getter . why do we need to add properties for public fields? I already access to public variables from everywhere . how can you control me with setter and getter?Thanks...

Comment: No need for getters and setters for public variables.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ankit sais. You dont need setters and getters. It's just a better way to control behavior. For example. If you want to get a string but you notice that you sometimes get a trailing space at the end. Then you could modify the getter to do `return theString.trim()`. There is no way to do that accessing a public variable

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Main event is priority. For example Im a programmer and I wrote a class . My class has a public int id field with properties and I sent my class to my other programmer. He can directly change id field. where is my setter getter gone? properties are unnecessary? right?